# What is the minimum of $\sec A +\sec B + \sec C$ if $ABC$ is an acute angled triangle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

In an acute angled triangle $ABC$, what is the least value of $\sec A + \sec B + \sec C$?

My Approach: I tried doing this by graph and assuming a triangle in it. Answer is coming , but is there any easy way to do such kind of problems.

Comment: Another option might be to consider $C$ constant and differentiate $\sec A +\sec B$, keeping in mind $A+B$ is constant too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the interval $\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, $f(x) = \sec(x)$ is convex. Apply Jensen's inequality to get
\begin{equation*}
\sec\left(\frac{A+B+C}{3}\right) \leq \frac{1}{3}\left(\sec(A)+\sec(B)+\sec(C)\right)
\end{equation*}
Since $\sec(\frac{\pi}{3}) = 2$, the result follows.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not asked for a proof and can take the "problemorphic" approach (that is, assuming that because this was posed as a problem that implies there is a unique answer) then the only possible answer is for an equilateral triangle, where $\sec A = \sec B = \sec C = 2$ so the answer is $6$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint;

$$ cos A + cos B +cos C ≤ 3/2$$(The proof  is a bit long )

Use

$$  HM  ≤   AM$$

And we have what we are looking for

So
$$9/(sec A +sec B +sec C) ≤  3/2$$

Answer (score 1):

Equilateral triangle is the triangle in which we get the maximum/minimum values of trigonometric expressions.Put $A=B=C=\frac{\pi}{3}$ to get the minimum value of $\sec A+\sec B+\sec C$