# If $xyz = x+y+z$ for $x,y,z > 0$, then $\sqrt{1+x^2} + \sqrt{1+y^2} + \sqrt{1+z^2} \ge 6$

Tags: analysis, inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> If $x,y,z \in \Bbb R_{>0}$ satisfy $xyz = x+y+z$, prove that $$\sqrt{1+x^2} + \sqrt{1+y^2} + \sqrt{1+z^2} \ge 6$$

We can express $1+x^2$ as
$$1+x^2 = (1-xy)(1-xz) = \frac{(y-xyz)(z-xyz)}{yz} = \frac{(x+z)(x+y)}{yz}$$
since $x + y + z = xyz$ implies $1+ x^2 + xy + xz = 1 + x^2yz$. Thus, our desired inequality boils down to
$$\sqrt{\frac{(x+z)(x+y)}{yz}} + \sqrt{\frac{(y+z)(y+x)}{xz}} + \sqrt{\frac{(z+x)(z+y)}{xy}} \ge 6$$
which looks more complicated. Perhaps I am not headed in the right direction? I'd appreciate any hints or solutions. Thank you!

Comment: Hint: if $x+y+z=xyz$, then we can set a triangle $ABC$ such that $x=\tan A,y=\tan B, z=\tan C$. then consider Jenson's inequality or other possible methods you can think of.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1847073/what-is-the-minimum-of-sec-a-sec-b-sec-c-if-abc-is-an-acute-angled-tri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea gives a simple solution.

Indeed, by AM-GM twice we obtain: $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{(x+y)(x+z)}{yz}}\geq3\sqrt[3]{\frac{\prod\limits_{cyc}(x+y)}{xyz}}\geq3\sqrt[3]{\frac{8xyz}{xyz}}=6.$$

Answer (score 3):

We have: $$xyz = x+y+z \ge 3\sqrt[3]{xyz} \Longrightarrow xyz \ge 3^{3/2}$$
and for $a\in \{x,y,z \}$:
$$\sqrt{1+a^2} = \sqrt{1+\frac{a^2}{3}+\frac{a^2}{3}+\frac{a^2}{3}}\ge\sqrt{4\sqrt[4]{\frac{a^6}{3^3}}}=\frac{2}{3^{3/8}}\cdot a^{3/4}$$
Then
$$\begin{align}
LHS &\ge \frac{2}{3^{3/8}}\cdot \left(x^{3/4}+y^{3/4}+z^{3/4}  \right) \ge \frac{2}{3^{3/8}}\cdot3\cdot\sqrt[3]{(xyz)^{3/4}}= \frac{6}{3^{3/8}}(xyz)^{1/4}\\ & \ge \frac{6}{3^{3/8}} \cdot 3^{\frac{3}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{4}} = 6
\end{align}$$
The equality occurs when $ x=y=z= \sqrt{3}$.

Q.E.D